# How to upload file and save it directly to MongoDB using GridFS

Tags: ruby, mongodb, sinatra, gridfs

I have a Sinatra application hosted on heroku and I'm trying to enable file uploading. I know heroku doesn't allow saving to the file system so I'm trying to save the image to MongoDB using GridFS directly. But I don’t know how.
Using the code below, I'm able to save to file system

```
base_dir = Dir.pwd + "/static/images/channels/"
File.open("#{base_dir}" + params['logo'][:filename], "w") do |f|
  f.write(params['logo'][:tempfile].read)
end
```

How do I save the file directly to MongoDB without first saving it to the file system?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the GridFS API to basically do what you're doing above, but write to MongoDB: http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/GridFileSystem.html#open-instance_method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to upload the file as binary data to a database.
You can use `PaperClip` to upload files and then store them as binary to MangoDB.
here [this link](http://blog.wyeworks.com/2010/2/10/making-paperclip-work-with-sinatra-datamapper/) might help you out:

Answer (score 0):

If your files are actually less than 16 mb, please try using this Converter that changes the image of format jpeg / png to a format of saving to mongodb, and you can see this as an easy alternative for gridfs ,

please follow this github repo for more details

https://github.com/saran-surya/Mongo-Image-Converter